# fb-walls module for drupal

Tags: facebook, drupal

I'm learning my way around drupal a little bit by making someone a site. I'm asked to display facebook wall posts in a block.
I found [this](http://neosmart.de/social-media/fb-wall) module. Now I have no clue how to get started on this.

What I  do know is that in drupal>admin>configuration>facebook-wall I need to fill in an application ID of the wall and then the secret code. But I have no clue on how retrieve that. I searched here in SO and using google but all I'm lead to is the facebook developer's pages where it's talking about app creation and developer's stuff I don't understand (eventhough I know a little basic php).

I simply don't know where to start looking, so I guess all i'm asking is for a little more understandable resource to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to start here

https://developers.facebook.com/

And since your developing for a website you would want to click the website option, which brings you to here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

If you read that page, not even a quarter of the way down, you would see something about Authentication... Which in the first paragraph makes mention of your AppID, and gives you some other links to follow.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication

Which talks about how the authentication process works, and then there is

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Which is used to register you application, which the paragraph it is linked in mentions you need to do in order to use Facebook on your website (which is what your trying to do). Clicking on that link should be pretty self explanatory at that point as to how to get your AppID and Secret.

There you go, I have reduced the amount of reading you now need to do to a level that should be manageable....

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. Iwas going through those pages you mentioned before Istarted all this. Im feeling very retarded and frustrated.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/
This page has indeed the link that says 'register your website' with facebook to get an app ID. What this link does is lead me to 

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ Which allows allows me to go back to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/. Nothing about how to get app ID. 

And the other page you mention, assumes from the very beginning that you have the application ID.

Comment: If im not mistaken, at the top of the Apps page there should be a button that says Create New App. I cant be for certain as I already have an app setup, and thus it shows me the information for my app when i click on it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; I also just started reading through Graph API to try and makes sense out of this. I did the create app thing but something went wrong the the cell phone code. Also, still don't understand why I need to create an app and give it a name while All I'm trying to do is have my facebook wall feeding my site and retrieving an app ID of an existing app.